# How to Change Vector Datasource in QGIS 3.2.0?

Tags: qgis, postgresql, data-source, qgis-3

QGIS 2.18 has a very good function **Change Vector Datasource**:

[image]

In QGIS 3.2.0 there is **Update SQL layer** but it doesn't work like *Change Vector Datasource*. When I open it, select and do update, it acts in the way shown below on screenshots.

Please help how to change vector datasource as easy as in 2.18.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Update: **changeDataSource** plugin [has been updated](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/changeDataSource/version/3.0/) for QGIS 3.x.

Comment: My favourite plugin!

Answer (score 4):

In qgis 2 this functionality was not native but came from a plugin ([changeDataSource](https://geogear.wordpress.com/2016/01/29/changedatasourceplugin-plugin-release-2-0/)), it seem this plugin has not been ported to qgis 3. You could try to contact the plugin creator to made this happen (by sponsoring the upgrade or helping with the migration...)

You could also propose for this fonctionality to be added in qgis core (again more likely to happen and/or quicker if you sponsor it or contribute)